# Duplicate listen error with Asp Net Core Nginx Multiple Domain

Tags: asp.net, linux, asp.net-core, nginx

I am trying to host multiple ASP NET Core sites with different domains on Linux, Unbunt 18.04 and using nginx as reverse proxy.

I got error as "*duplicate listen options for 80*". What is reason for this error and How can I solve this error?

The default nginx conf is:

```
server {

    listen 80;

    server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}

server {

    listen 80;

    server_name domain2.com domain2.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://localhost:5005;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

}
```

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration that Nginx is reading.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a sigle file for each app...
for **domain1.com** you can create an archive domain1.com like this:

```
upstream app1{
server 192.168.1.250:5000;
}

server {

server_name domain1.com www.domain1.com;    
listen     80;

#Redirects  traffic
location / {
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;
    proxy_pass http://app1;
  }
}
```

for **domain2.com** you can create an archive domain2.com like this:

```
upstream app2{
server 192.168.1.250:5005;
}

server {

server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;    
listen     80;

#Redirects  traffic
location / {
    proxy_redirect          off;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    client_max_body_size    10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
    proxy_connect_timeout   90;
    proxy_send_timeout      90;
    proxy_read_timeout      90;
    proxy_buffers           32 4k;
    proxy_pass http://app2;
  }
}
```